# Can't run a discord.py script due to pylint error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord.py, pylint

I am newbie learning discord.py Rewrite. I just wrote a small code for making a discord bot online and run the ping command. At the the first time, it was working fine, then it started saying error in Visual Studio Code that its a pylint error which can't export the discord file. The error is `unable to import 'discord' and 'discord.ext'`

My code is like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '_')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ('The Bot is ready')
    
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send (f'Pong!{(round(client.latency * 1000))}ms')
    
client.run('BOT_TOKEN')
```

Comment: Following the guidelines of StackOverflow, code or logs should be provided in text format, not images. Can you refer to the guide below and correct it?
[how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  /  [do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Pylint does not prevent a script from running.

Comment: You can simply run it, the pylint error can be annoying, but it doesn't prevent from running you the script as Klaus D. said

Comment: @TheProN00B -Please check whether the imported module "discord" has changed the folder location or currently running file has changed location relative to "discord".

Answer (score 1):

You didnt import discord.py library:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '_')

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print ('The Bot is ready')
    
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send (f'Pong!(round(client.latency*1000))ms')
    
client.run ('BOT_TOKEN')
```

If it won't help you, you should install it. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/